# Angular.js Error: $injector:modulerr

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to make a simple project where i want to populate the section with ng-view directive and i keep getting the following error:
I also included in index.html the angular files:
1-angular min js
2-angular-route min js
3-angular-resource min js

```
 Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error Failed to instantiate module
 booksInventoryApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

How can i fix this?

My code is:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="booksInventoryApp">
<body>
    <section ng-view></section>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp', ['booksInventoryApp.bsm','booksInventoryApp.allBooks']);

//route provider
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider

    // route for the index page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : '../allBooks.html',
        controller  : 'booksCtrl'
    })

    // route for the best selling month page
    .when('/bsm/:id', {
        templateUrl : 'bsm.html',
        controller  : 'bsmCtrl'
    })

    // route for the root
    .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });

}]);
```

**bsm.js**

```
 var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp.bsm', []);

 app.controller('bsmCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.book = "Bla Bla";
});
```

**bsm.html**

```
<section class="container">
{{book}}
</section>
```

**allBooks.js**

```
var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp.allBooks', []);

// controllers
app.controller('booksCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://whispering-woodland-9020.herokuapp.com/getAllBooks")
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;          
     });
});
```

**allBooks.html**

```
        <section class="row">
          <section class="col-sm-6 col-md-2" ng-repeat="book in data.books">
            <section class="thumbnail">
              <img ng-src="{{book.url}}">
              <section class="caption">
                <h3>{{book.name}}</h3>
                <p>Author: {{book.author}}</p>
                <p>ID: <span class="badge">{{book.id}}</span></p>
                <p>Available: <span class="badge">{{book.amount}}</span></p>
                <p>Price: <span class="badge">${{book.price}}</span></p>
                <p><a ng-src="#/bsm/{{book.id}}"><button class="btn btn-info">Best selling month</button></a></p>
              </section>
            </section>
          </section>
        </section>
```

Comment: You have not included the other scripts in your html, `bsm.js` and `allBooks.js`.load them then load `index.js`. Also where is angularjs scripts loaded (error suggests you are loading it but not shown in the code the question)?

Comment: Try changing booksInventoryApp to booksinventoryapp

Comment: @PSL omg if that works im so stupid EDIT: that was not the reaseon. maybe something else is wrong

Comment: @Bioto Tried that too. That is not the issue

Comment: @user4440845 Click on the error link, that will give you the clue... You must be missing some module that you are using. eg: where do you think you will get the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `ngRoute` module in your app and also the script reference of the `angular-route.min.js` write after the `angular.js`, Also you need to add `bsm.js` and `allBooks.js` in your html after above two mentioned file has loaded.

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp', [
      'booksInventoryApp.bsm',
      'booksInventoryApp.allBooks', 
      'ngRoute'
]);
```

**Note**

> Both the version of `angular.js` & `angular.route.js` should be the
>   same otherwise it will show some wierd issue. Preferred version is **1.3.15**

Comment: That is what i have missed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html page you not included `bsm.js` and `allBooks.js` files which contains the required dependencies of your app.

Since you have specified the dependency of `'booksInventoryApp.bsm','booksInventoryApp.allBooks'` in your app angular is not able to find those modules and hence you are getting that error.

Also you need to include angular route script reference and `ngRoute` in your dependencies because you are using angular routing in your app.

`var app = angular.module('booksInventoryApp', ['ngRoute', 'booksInventoryApp.bsm', 'booksInventoryApp.allBooks']);`

Comment: main ng-route thing is missing here dude

Comment: Yes was editing my answer before that your down voted :(